# In ios 7 how to display alert with standard warning icon?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to display an alert with standard warning icon before the title. Is it possible easy way (i.e. some standard behavior) or I have to implement custom UIAlertView.

Comment: show the screen shot which type u need

Comment: Note also that "almost everyone" uses MBProgressHUD (just google) in almost every project - it's almost essential in iOS.

Comment: 10x, [Joe Blow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/joe-blow). I will take that into account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"\u26A0" should display an alert icon, put it before your title

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\u26A0 title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

[image: Results :]

Comment: Just what I need, 10x!

Comment: If this answer is what you needed, don't forget to accept it ;)

Comment: But it's really ugly, how to make the icon display on the middle left of the view?

Comment: @Gank If you need an non standard behavior you'll have to implement or use an open-source custom Alertview.
There are a lot of nice looking alertview available with cocoapods : https://cocoapods.org/?q=alertview